# Why does my C code cause Visual Studio to crash?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to write code in C that will count the words from a text file (in this case, the text file has a list of names). After it finds the number of names in the text file, I want to prompt the user to enter a score (between 0 - 100) for each name, and then calculate an average score. However, every time I try to run it my program, it crashes and this pops up:

[image: Visual Studio has crashed]

And here is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
/*
1.  Read a list of names from a file called names.txt
2.  Count the number of names in the list.
3.  Prompt the user to provide a score (0 – 100) for each name in the file.
4.  Output the name and corresponding score to the file names_scores.txt
*/
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1//inside a word
#define OUT 0//outside a word

/*count lines, words, and characters in input*/
int main()
{
    int c;//storage variable for nw delimiters
    int nl;//new line
    int nw;//new word
    int nc;//next new character towards EOF 
    int nwCount;//number of words found in .txt file

    int state = OUT;//Indicates whether we're inside or outside of a word. We initialize
                    //it to being outside of the first word in the .txt file.

    nl = nw = nc = nwCount = 0;
    FILE *myFile = fopen_s("pfile", "names.txt", "r");
    if (myFile == NULL){
        perror("Error opening file.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    while ((c = _fgetchar()) != EOF){//let 'c' act as a storage variable for the nw delimiters

        ++nc;//increment the curent new character (do we need this incrementer?)
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){//nw delimiters
            state = OUT;
        }
        else {//if (state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            for (nwCount = 0; nwCount < 6; nwCount++){
                scanf_s("%d", &nw);
                nwCount += nw;
            }
        }   

    }//end of while loop

    //printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);//test the word counter

    int score = 0;
    int scoreQty = 0;
    int scoreSum = 0;
    int scoreAverage = 0;//scoreAverage = scoreSum / nwCount

    printf("There are ");
    printf("%d", nwCount);
    printf(" names in the names.txt file.\n");

    printf("Please enter a score integer (between 0 - 100) for each name.\n\n");
    for (scoreQty = 0; scoreQty < nwCount; scoreQty++){
        scanf_s("%d", &score);
        scoreSum += score;
    }

    printf("\nThe average score is: ");
    printf("%d %", scoreSum / scoreQty);
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 as a compiler.

Comment: Debuggers are excellent at helping you find crash issues like this.  Did you try clicking the "Debug" button in the error dialog?

Comment: Does not look like you really brought your IDE down...

Comment: The mixture of `_fgetchar()`, whatever that is, and `scanf_s()` looks highly suspicious. `scanf_s()` won't ready anything from files for you, unless you're redirecting one to standard input. According to Microsoft, `_fgetchar()` doesn't read anything from files, either.

Comment: Well, if `scoreQty` is 0, you have a divide by 0 error on your last `printf`.

Comment: You also have a bad format string on the last line.  To print a "%", you have to use "%%". So your program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Cause of the crash is the reason that the call of `fopen_s` is incorrect.

change

```
FILE *myFile = fopen_s("pfile", "names.txt", "r");
```

to

```
errno_t err;
FILE *myFile;
err = fopen_s(&myFile, "names.txt", "r");
```

see [fopen_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx)